# Nexus 7 actual screen size

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, nexus-7

I built a simple application for Nexus 7. I used the following code to get the screen size in DP units.

```
this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp;
this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenHeightDp;
```

where "this" is MainActivity context object.

I get these values: 600 dp for width and 888 dp for height.

Pixel density is `tvdpi` which is 213, and the ratio of dp to pixels is 1.33

I used this formula

```
pixels = dips * (density / 160)
```

which gives me for height

```
pixels = 888 * (213 / 160) = 1182.15.
```

I know that pixel size of the Nexus 7 screen is 800 x 1280. Where are the missing 100 pixels of height in this calculation? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Configuration.screenHeightDp()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenHeightDp) returns the dimensions of the *available area* of the screen.

Your calculated value, 1182, is close to the the height in pixels [minus the navigation bar and status bar](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/242856-nexus-7-display-measurements-pixels.html#post2511598) (1173) of the Nexus 7, in other words the resolution available for your app to use.

Full screen apps should be able to use the full 1280 resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you the actual display size as a Point:

```
    private Point getDisplaySize(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        return getDisplaySizeMinSdk17(context);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
        return getDisplaySizeMinSdk13(context);
    } else {
        return getDisplaySizeMinSdk1(context);
    }
}

@TargetApi(17)
private Point getDisplaySizeMinSdk17(Context context) {
    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getRealMetrics(metrics);

    final Point size = new Point();
    size.x = metrics.widthPixels;
    size.y = metrics.heightPixels;

    return size;
}

@TargetApi(13)
private Point getDisplaySizeMinSdk13(Context context) {

    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    return size;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Point getDisplaySizeMinSdk1(Context context) {

    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point size = new Point();
    size.x = display.getWidth();
    size.y = display.getHeight();

    return size;
}
```